# QDirIterator - Skip Folders and its subfolders

Tags: c++, qt, directory

How can you skip folders with the QDirIterator?
I've tried it with:

```
QString nameFilter = "*.h";
QDirIterator dirIterator(folder, nameFilter, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
QString str("folder");
QStringList filenames;

while (dirIterator.hasNext())
{            
    if(dirIterator.next() == str) continue;

    filenames.append(dirIterator.next());
}
```

but it only ignores the specific folder but not its subdirectories.
Any idea?

Comment: what is your problem exactly? do you want to iterate all folders and subfolders to find `.h` files?

Comment: Yes, i want to find all h-files in my folders and subfolders. But i have a list of folders which i don't want to search in. Subfolders of this folder should also be ignored.

Comment: I will give you answer, wait for it please...

Comment: I did it, i changed my answer, it working perfectly!!!

Comment: Your iterator advances twice in the loop.

Comment: I answered your question, check my answer changes!

Answer (score 0):

Bellow instruction working 100 percent :

This method `QString QDirIterator::next()` Advances the iterator to the next entry, and returns the "file path" of this new entry. If `hasNext()` returns `false`, this function does nothing, and returns a `null QString`.

If `QDirIterator` found a file with specific `filter` (based on `const QStringList &nameFilters` parameter) then `QDirIterator::next()` returns "file-path" and you  cannot compare the whole "file-path" with "skiped-folder" to iterate!

Because of this i had to write a function as a directory parser as bellow :

```
QStringList Widget::getCurrDirsOfFile(const QFileInfo &file_info, const QString &default_folder)
{
    QString file_path = file_info.filePath();
    QString file_name = file_info.fileName();
    file_path.truncate(file_path.lastIndexOf("/" + file_name));

    file_path = file_path.mid(file_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    return file_path;
}
```

This function get "file-path" and return last "folder-name's" of it like bellow :

```
input : /home/msi/Desktop/123/untitled/123/widget.h
output(list) : 123, 123
```

We have `QString skiped_dir("untitled");` as skiped folders!

In this state when you got something excluding `123` "folder-name's", you can append that file to `QStringList filenames` :

```
if(folder_list.indexOf(QRegExp(skiped_dir)) == -1)
        filenames.append(it.filePath());
```

So try this (notice in comments) :

```
void Widget::btn_iterate_clicked()
{
    // folder to iterate
    QString folder("/home/msi/Desktop/");

    // folder-name you want to skip
    QString skiped_dir("untitled");

    // file-names which are match with .h filter stored in filenames list
    QStringList filenames;

    // this list used in QStringList getCurrDirsOfFile() method
    QStringList folder_list;

    // iterator
    QDirIterator it(folder, QStringList() << "*.h" , QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext())     // if next object exist for iterate
    {
        // we have the file with .h extension
        it.next();

        // get previous folders that exist in filepath address of it.fileInfo()
        folder_list = getCurrDirsOfFile(it.fileInfo(), folder);

        // if folder_list contained skiped folder then reject that or appent it
        if(folder_list.indexOf(QRegExp(skiped_dir)) == -1)
            filenames.append(it.filePath());
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < filenames.count();i++)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "", filenames.at(i));
    }
}
```

Suppose we have bellow tree (directories) :

This program just shows :

```
/home/msi/Desktop/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/ui_widget.h
/home/msi/Desktop/1/1.h
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't get it working. Maybe my intention wasn't explained exactly.
I'm searching for all *.h-Files in a directory and its subdirectories. But i want to exclude some directories and their subdirectories while searching for the h-files.

Comment: @woidler this is a new answer, its  absolutely working

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but your original code was close...there's two problems. First, the iterator covers every entry and what it returns is a full path and filename, not just the entry name within the current directory. Checking for an exact match is the problem rather than for containment. The second issue is that you have two calls to "next" without a call to "hasNext" between them, so it's possible you'll have a crash.

```
while (dirIterator.hasNext())
{      
    QString fname = dirIterator.next ();

    if (fname.contains (str)) continue;

    filenames.append (fname);
}
```

Note that you may need to be more specific with the value of "str". Any filename could contain the word "folder", so you'll probably want to check for str.endsWith ("/folder") as well as str.contains ("/folder/").

If you inspect the values returned from "next", you'll better see how to compare what you're excluding to the current entry, so just tweak the string comparison to get what you want.